# Unix menu shell script: adding, listing, and extracting files to .tar

Tags: shell, unix, menu, terminal, tar

I'm trying to create a menu based script that has 3 options 
1. add files to .tar
2. list the contents of .tar
3. extract the tar file contents

This is what I have so far. I'm still new to unix so yeah.

```
#!/bin/sh
#script2

PS3='Enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1: Add file to .tar" "Option 2: List contents of .tar" "Option 3: Extract         contents"$
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
            "Option 1")
                    echo "you chose choice 1"
                    tar -rf file.tar file2add
                    ;;
            "Option 2")
                    echo "you chose choice 2"
                    tar -tf file.tar
                    ;;
            "Option 3")
                    echo "you chose choice 3"

                    ;;
            "Quit")
                    break
                    ;;
            *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

[IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/29gen0o.png[/IMG]

Comment: Stackoverflow supports syntax highlighting.  Can you please put your code in your post?  Also, what problem are you having?

Comment: Well im trying to get the options to do the above functions, i just keep getting that is an invalid option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really want your script to work with minimal dependencies (i.e. only with `sh`), consider using a [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) program that makes it somewhat easier to program text-mode menus.